# How do I get Chrome to apply font smoothing during FadeIn()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a large title I wish to fade in gradually after the page loads. I'm using the following jQuery code snippet to make this happen.

```
$('#primary').fadeIn(1000);
```

However, during the transition Chrome seemingly does not apply anti-aliasing (or font smoothing) until the effect is finished. This produces a noticeable jerk after the fade in ends and font smoothing is applied. IE, Firefox and Safari all work fine.

It's the difference between this...

[image]

And this...

[image]

This can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/68Bmd/

Any ideas on how I can get Chrome to apply font smoothing during the fade in?

P.S. I'm aware I can disable font smoothing. This removes the jerk, but it leaves the fonts looking terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to put a shadow in front of the title and fade that out, and it seems to work.

the html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="shadow"></div>
    <h1 id="primary">This is a Title</h1>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#shadow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57x88/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS solution using animation.  Note, if using in Chrome, you'll need to add browser prefix.

```
@keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        color: #fff;   
    }

    to {
        color: #000;
    }
}

#primary {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    animation: fade-in 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: As a warning, do not use footers to promote your website. I'm removing all of these.